# Get value of token in header response of AFNetworking swift

Tags: swift, swift3, afnetworking

I have some POST webservices that they have token value in header field
How can I read this value ?
I googled but all answers is just for set value in header field
here is my registration function that I call it in another file
and I want access header in didReciveDataFromRegisterWebService and use token for later webservices

```
func register(phone : String) {
    let configuration = URLSessionConfiguration.default
    let manager = AFURLSessionManager(sessionConfiguration: configuration)
    manager.responseSerializer = AFHTTPResponseSerializer()
    let req = AFHTTPRequestSerializer().request(withMethod: "POST", urlString: "http://192.168.1.228:8000/gcab/v1/driver/register", parameters: nil, error: nil)
    req.setValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
    let insideDict  = ["phone_number" : phone , "device_id" : DeveloperAssistant.getDeviceID() ]
    let insideString = insideDict.convertToString()
    let jsonString = "data=\(insideString)"
    let jsonPostData = jsonString.data(using: .utf8)
    req.httpBody = jsonPostData!     
    let dataTask = manager.dataTask(with: req as URLRequest) { (response : URLResponse, data : Any?, error : Error?) in
        if data != nil {
            do{...}
            else{
                    let responseData =  WebServiceParser.parseDataToObject(data: dict, type: .register) as! RegisterWebServiceResponse
                    self.registerDelegate?.didReciveDataFromRegisterWebService!(data: responseData, error: nil, response: nil)
                }                   
                print("dict info is : \(dictInfo)")
            }catch let erro {
                print("erro darim \(erro)")
            }
            print("we have data ")
        }else{
            print("we don't have data")
        }
    }
    dataTask.resume()   
}
```

Comment: Can you show us your code doing the network request?

Comment: @ozgur here is my code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why you are using `AFNetworking`? I used this lib a lot in `Objective-C` but since `Swift` came out I changed to [`Alamofire`](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire) because it is written in `Swift` and very well maintained.

This could help you (not tested!). 
Inside your completion handler:

```
if let response = dataTask.response as? NSHTTPURLResponse {

    if let headerFieldValue =  response.allHeaderFields["YOUR_HEADER_FIELD"] as? String {

        // do somthing 
    }
}
```

Here is one short example of how to access one `response headerField` with `Alamofire`. 
`HTTPURLResponse` has a `Dictionary` property called `allHeaderFields` from which you can access your token value. Here I cast this to `String`

```
Alamofire.request("https://serviceURL.de", method: .post, parameters: parameters, encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: nil).responseJSON { (response:DataResponse<Any>) in

        if let headerFieldValue =  response.response?.allHeaderFields["YOUR_HEADER_FIELD"] as? String {

            // do somthing 
        }

}
```

Comment: your code doesn't work 
but I switch to alamofire thank you so much

Comment: is alamofire good for post request that they have http body ?